# If maximum value of $f(x)=\frac{3\sqrt{2x^2+x}}{2x^2+x+2\sin^2\theta}$ (where $x\gt0$) is $\frac3{√2}$ then $\theta$ may lie in

Tags: calculus, functions, contest-math, maxima-minima

**Question:**

If maximum value of $f(x)=\frac{3\sqrt{2x^2+x}}{2x^2+x+2\sin^2\theta}$ (where $x\gt0$) is $\frac3{√2}$ then $\theta$ may lie in

A) $(-\fracπ6,\fracπ6)$

B) $(-\fracπ4,\fracπ4)$

C) $(-\fracπ3,\fracπ3)$

D) $(-π,π)$

**My Attempt:**

$\frac{3\sqrt{2x^2+x}}{2x^2+x+2(1)}  \le f(x)\le\frac{3\sqrt{2x^2+x}}{2x^2+x+2(0)}$

$\frac{3}{\sqrt{2x^2+x}+\frac2{\sqrt{2x^2+x}}}  \le f(x)\le\frac{3}{\sqrt{2x^2+x}}$

Not sure what to do next.

**Edit:**

$f'(x)=\frac{(2x^2+x+2\sin^2\theta)\frac{3(4x+1)}{2\sqrt{2x^2+x}}-3\sqrt{2x^2+x}(4x+1)}{(2x^2+x+2\sin^2\theta)^2}$

Numerator is $3(4x+1)(2x^2+x+2\sin^2\theta-2(2x^2+x))$

i.e. $(2\sin^2\theta-2x^2-x))$

Comment: Substitute $t=\sqrt{2x^2+x}.$ The expression will become simpler. Then use the fact $t^2+a^2\ge 2|a|t$ where $a=\sin\theta.$ Hence $|\sin \theta|={1\over \sqrt{2}}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc so, answer should be CD, right? But the answer given is BCD.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc also, with $\sin\theta=\frac1{√2}$, aren't we getting maximum value as $\frac32?$

Comment: Sorry, I have missed the coefficient $2$ in front of\sin^2\theta.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I have added an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=\sqrt{2x^2+x}.$ Then $t>0$ and $t$ admits all the values from $(0,\infty).$ The function takes the form
$${3t\over t^2+2\sin^2\theta}\qquad (*)$$ The inequality $t^2+a^2\ge 2|a|\,t$ implies ($a=\sqrt{2}\sin\theta$)
$$t^2+2\sin^2\theta\ge 2\sqrt{2}|\sin \theta|\, t$$ and the equality occurs when $t=|a|=\sqrt{2}|\sin\theta|.$ Hence the minimal value of $(*)$ is equal ${3\over 2\sqrt{2}|\sin\theta|}.$ Hence $|\sin \theta|={1\over 2}.$ In the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ the only solutions are $\theta=\pm {\pi\over 6}$ and $\theta=\pm {5\pi\over 6}.$ Thus B, C and  D may occur unlike A.